# Have python http server create a second web page

Tags: python, http, get, server

I have a server that writes a web page with a form. The user fills in the form and presses submit which is handled by do_GET.
Based on the information submitted I want the server to close the web page and write a new page.

Comment: The HTTP server can only respond to HTTP requests. On the other hand, the GET handlers (e.g. the do_GET) can generate any output depending on your request.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far, and let us know where in the process you are stuck or have an error you can't resolve?